# Error updating WP-CLI

Tags: updates, wp-cli, command-line

Below is the output from my attempt to update wp-cli on Windows 10. Clearly another version is available. Can someone please explain how to make this work?

```
C:\Users\HP>wp cli update
Error: You can only self-update Phar files.

C:\Users\HP>wp cli check-update
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| version | update_type | package_url                                                                 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1.1.0   | major       | https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/releases/download/v1.1.0/wp-cli-1.1.0.phar |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How is your copy of WP CLI installed? The message indicates that you have not used the standard WP CLI installation method of downloading and moving a `.phar` file

Comment: I installed it thusly:
 `composer global require wp-cli/wp-cli`
`composer global require psy/psysh`

Comment: have you tried updating it with `composer`?

Comment: @Robin Did you manage to update WP-CLI?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, locate your installation of WP-CLI.

---

If you're using Composer you can list all globally installed packages on the command line like this:

```
composer global show
```

Then update the WP-CLI composer package:

```
composer global update wp-cli/wp-cli
```

---

If you're using Homebrew, you can list all installed packages on the command line like this:

```
brew list
```

And update the package:

```
brew upgrade wp-cli
```

---

After that you should be able to upgrade to the next version of WP-CLI via the built-in command:

```
wp cli update
```

In return, you'll get a prompt like this:

```
You have version 1.4.1. Would you like to update to 1.5.0? [y/n]


Downloading from https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/releases/download/v1.5.0...
New version works. Proceeding to replace.
Success: Updated WP-CLI to 1.5.0.
```

Comment: I have version 1.5.0, when I run `wp cli check-update` it says 2.0.0 is available, but when I run `composer global update wp-cli/wp-cli` it says it's already updated, and I also got "You can only self-update Phar files" when I try to run `wp cli update` :|